# How do I provide my own message source to react-intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, ember-intl

I have an Ember application with some React components in it. Some of the components expect to be wrapped in an IntlProvider.  I'd like to create a subclass/replacement IntlProvider that, instead of looking in an array of messages for a translation, delegates to ember-intl (where it would call a function for the translation).  Any pointers on where I could start with this?